# GSON date serialize JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, gson

I have a custom object with name DateTime . I register TypeAdapter with method registerTypeAdapter . I think  GSON ignores this adapter . GSON how to detect date in json object ? is it required establishing any link between adapter and format of string in json ?

```
   builder.registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<DateTime>() 
          {

            public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1,JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException 
            {
                try{return new DateTime(arg0.getAsString());}
                catch (Exception e){
                    return null;
                    }
            }
});
```

Comment: I've seen dates being serialized as Long and as Javascript date String. So detecting a Date depends on the serialization.

Comment: string pattern of my date is different from  usual date pattern.  GSON    detect this property as a date but it uses its default date type adapter .

Comment: What class are you marshaling to?

Comment: I have a class with name : Person.java. this class has a DateTime field. DateTime is written by me as a custom date class. I'm deserializing Person as using GSON but GSON doesn't deserialize DateTime field . Because it doesn't use my TypeAdapter , it uses its own default date adapter.

Comment: Are you sure you don't run into an exception which is caught and cases `null` to be returned?

Comment: com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters.DefaultDateTypeAdapter runs . I want to run my type adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Json comes in name/value pairs. You're almost certainly getting an exception and eating it. You need to pull out the value of the name/value pair to pass into the new DateTime. If your JSON is something like { "date": 213424234 } then you'd need to do this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get( "date" ).getAsLong());
```